# How to change non-numeric value in csv (like encoding)

Tags: database, csv

For example, I have csv file

```
1, a, 10, 1

1, a, 10, 3

2, b, 18, 2

1, c, 17, 3

3, a, 12, 6

1, d,  1, 4
```

For 2nd column, it does not have numeric value,
There are four different non-numeric value types `[a,b,c,d]`. So I want to encode `'a' as 1, 'b' as 2, 'c' as 3, 'd' as 4`

then csv file will be

```
1, 1, 10, 1

1, 1, 10, 3

2, 2, 18, 2

1, 3, 17, 3

3, 1, 12, 6

1, 4,  1, 4
```

The problem is csv is too large (more than 1M rows, 100 columns).
So I don't have all possible non-numeric values (for example, [a,b,c,d]) for each column

I don't know which keyword should I use for googling.

Comment: What is exactly your question? Are you having problem with the csv file is too large (e.g. can't be loaded to the memory), or you need help with how you can transform the second column to numeric values when you don't know how many possible values there are?

Comment: My question is "how you can transform the second column to numeric values when you don't know how many possible values there are" and I hope it is not very slow for huge csv.

Comment: Next question is if you need help with writing a program (e.g. in Java), or you want help with using tool such as Excel?